# Why is my tkinter toplevel huge when I stated size constraints?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I'm aware this is probably a newb question, but I have yet to be able to find an answer. Here's a snippet of my code, that has a root window containing a button to open a Toplevel. The Toplevel pulls a random line from a text file to function as a sort of idea generator.

```
import random, fileinput
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Daydreamer')
#fname should be the file name of the image in working directory
fname = "bg.gif"
bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=fname)

#get width and height of image
w = bg_image.width()
h = bg_image.height()    

#size window correctly
    root.geometry("500x400")
    cv = tk.Canvas(width=w, height=h)
    cv.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
    cv.create_image(0,0,image=bg_image,anchor='nw')
    
    #add a frame for text
    mainframe=tk.Frame(root)
    
    #new window for inspirations
    def inspirations():
        top = Toplevel(root)
        top.geometry=("100x100")
        top.title("Inspiration")
        def idea():
            textidea=None
            for line in fileinput.input('textlist.txt'):
                if random.randrange(fileinput.lineno())==0:
                    textidea=line
            entrytext=tk.Text(top)
            entrytext.insert(INSERT, textidea)
            entrytext.insert(END, "Or press the Inspire Me button again for another idea!")
            entrytext.pack()
        idea()
            
 

           top.mainloop()
    
   
 
   
    #add buttons
    btn1 = tk.Button(cv, text="Inspire Me", command=inspirations)
    btn1.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=5, anchor='sw')
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Problem is, that Toplevel always comes out absolutely huge (larger than my root window), which looks incredibly silly for the small amount of content being displayed in it. Am I missing something really minute and stupid here? Help much appreciated.

Comment: This code has a lot of problems that prevent it from running. Please [edit] your question to include a working [mcve]. It would also help if your example used some hard-coded data instead of relying on an external file.

Comment: @BryanOakley Have done, thank you for pointing that out. The external file is literally just a plaintext list with new entries on each line, each about 10 words long.

Comment: There seems to be several lines of code unrelated to the question.  Why do we need all of those buttons? Won't one do, or does the problem only show up when you have three buttons? Also, you seem to be importing tkinter at least two different ways. Please show us how you're importing tkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley fixed again. sorry, you can tell python is not my strong suit.

Comment: Get rid of `top.geometry=("100x100")` ? and add padx and pady to the text box

Comment: @CoolCloud That adds a pack border, but still the window is huge. Thank you for your suggestion, though!

Comment: How huge is the window? include a screenshot please

Comment: Your code still contains errors. Tip: after posting, copy and paste the code into a new file and try to run the file. And please try to reduce the code down to a minimal example. For example, if you remove the background image does the program go away? If you use a hard-coded string rather than reading an exteral file, does it change anything. The key is to reduce the code down to the fewest lines possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't calling the `geometry` method, you're replacing it with a string.

Change this:

```
top.geometry=("100x100")
```

to this:

```
top.geometry("100x100")
```